# data getting in react data grid only if it has blank row in advance

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Notice for loop setting some row  but that i not needed
 but if i do not use it data is not getting in react data grid how to remove 
 the for loop from code?

Comment: Its not clear what you want to ask. Add some code and if possible add codesandbox as well.

Comment: Please add code instead of code within image with proper indentation. Don't create rowData variable outside of class. Create state variable within the class and update wherever required. Also there is no need for componentWillMount code.

Comment: i want to optimize the code and i do not want to use for loop..also i used this "componentWillMount " to access data from api before component is rendered